# How to get all jobs status via Spark Hidden Rest API

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark 1.6.2, and I am using the hidden REST API (http://arturmkrtchyan.com/apache-spark-hidden-rest-api).

How can I to get all jobs status in one rest call instead of using it for each - http://spark-cluster-ip:6066/v1/submissions/status/driver-20151008145126-0000 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on exactly what you need, you can use :8080/json to get a json representing all the applications. You should see an activeapps array which has a short info on each application (including its status e.g. Running):

For example, if I open up spark-shell I get the following field in the json:

```
"memoryused" : 82944,
  "activeapps" : [ {
    "starttime" : 1484638046648,
    "id" : "app-20170117022726-0113",
    "name" : "Spark shell",
    "cores" : 60,
    "user" : "assaf",
    "memoryperslave" : 27648,
    "submitdate" : "Tue Jan 17 02:27:26 EST 2017",
    "state" : "RUNNING",
    "duration" : 26954
  } ],
```

Note that this is basically adding /json to the UI port rather than going to the submission port.

Comment: What I need is to get jobs state, better not get everytime all jobs, but only the delta -> by timestamp or by list of submission ids

Comment: Can you expand? I thought you wanted all jobs together? The above gives you all the jobs currently running on the cluster with all their info. Can you provide an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to manage my executed jobs, for example, not execute another occurrence before the current has finished, so I want to check the job state. The API you mentioned return jobs which are in ‘Running Driver’ but I also want to know if the job is finished.
If when request http://spark-master:8081/json/ the job moved to ‘completed drivers’ I can’t get the information about it. I want to get all submission ids with the status in first stage, the better one is to get it with a filter (but let’s start simple)

Comment: I don't think you can do it with one call but if you enable the history server you can do two calls: The first as explained above to get running apps and the second through the history server REST api to get finished jobs